# Value cannot be null. Parameter name:connectionString

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using asp.net core 2.2 version

Below is my appSettingsDevelopment.JSON

```
{ 
 "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DatingApp.db"
  }
}
```

Below is my .csproj

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.2.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Below is how I am accessing connectionstring

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => 
         x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
     services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

I have seen and read all the related threads but somehow I am unable to fix this.
I get below mentioned errors:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Dating.API.Data.DataContext'.

Comment: How do you reference the json file? Most likely you did not load that file

Comment: Check the naming of the file. It appears you were trying to use environment naming convention ie `appSettings.Development.json`

Comment: Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)

Comment: I would first suggest you update json file name to match default naming convention. `appSettings.{Environment}.json`. If that does not work then explicitly load the settings file instead of injecting the default.

Comment: How can I load settings file any idea

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my previous comments?

Comment: I tried it didnt work

Comment: Then update the question with what you have tried.With you providing a [mcve], there is not much else we can do but guess as it could one or more of many different possibilities.

Comment: If you create a brand new code base and copy your relevant changes (from the snippets you've provided), does the problem persist? Also, are you on an operating system where case sensitivity in file names matters? (i.e. a Unix-like)

Comment: I had made a mistake I was not having connectionStrings rather connectionString